# Videos flicker in Chrome when one is positioned over the other?

Tags: css, html5-video

I am working with videos and sometimes need to show a short video over a stream. But in Chrome the videos start flickering kind of like underlying video is leaking into the one on the top. I tried `position: absolute`, `transform: translateY(-100%)` and `grid-area: 1/1/2/2` and the same result is produced in each case. It happens even if there is another non-transparent absolute positioned layer in between the two. It only works when an underlying video is hidden completely using `visibility: hidden`, `display: none` or other similar technique.

You can check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cpzxy8?file=index.js,index.html,style.css) to see for yourselves.

It works properly in Firefox but not in Chromium based browsers.

EDIT: it seems that this doesn't happen to everyone and is somehow linked to the hardware acceleration feature in Chrome. When I disable hardware acceleration the flickering stops for me also. Looks like a Chromium bug to me.

Comment: does adding `z-index` do nothing?

Comment: sadly it doesn't. even `isolation: isolate` does not help

Comment: It looks like your use case is like adding an ad into a stream - have to tested with the underlying video paused also when he video is showing on top?. It works fine in Safari also as an aside (with https rather than http urls).